# What are the restrictions on thread safety in RcppParallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp, tbb

I am sorry this question is hopelessly vague, but I have a MWE that does not work as I hoped it would (distilled down from a more complex problem I actually wanted to solve, so don't pooh-pooh it as being a toy.). First the `Rcpp` code:

```
// accumulate # of non-na elements seen on the input iterator.
void accum_nonna(RVector<double>::const_iterator vecit, 
                 RVector<double>::const_iterator end, 
                 RVector<int>::iterator xret) {
    for (;vecit != end;++vecit) { 
      if (! NumericVector::is_na(*vecit)) { *xret += 1; }
    }
}

struct MWE : public Worker
{   
   // source vector
   const RVector<double> input;
   // accumulated value
   RVector<int> output;

   // constructors
   MWE(const NumericVector input, IntegerVector output) : input(input), output(output) {}
   MWE(const MWE& mwes, Split) : input(mwes.input), output(mwes.output) {}

   // accumulate just the element of the range I have been asked to
   void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
       accum_nonna(input.begin() + begin, input.begin() + end, output.begin());
   }

   // join my value with that of another MWE
   void join(const MWE& rhs) { 
       output[0] += rhs.output[0];
   }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector dumbCount(NumericVector x) {
   // allocate the output
   IntegerVector output(1);
   // declare the instance
   MWE mwes(x,output);
   // call parallel_reduce to start the work
   parallelReduce(0, x.length(), mwes, 5000);
   // return the computed number of non-na elements
   return output;
```

}

As far as the user can see, you get a silly function in `R` called `dumbCount` that counts the number of non-NA elements in the input vector. It seems to work fine when the input is under the grain size of 5000, but does not work when over it:

```
> source('mwe.cpp')
> dumbCount(rnorm(4995))
[1] 4995
> dumbCount(rnorm(5005)) 
[1] 7112
```

Clearly I have done something that is not threadsafe. 
I would suspect the `join` operation, but I noticed that when I change the code in `operator()` to `output[0] = end - begin;` (to solve a different toy problem) I get an entirely *different* failure mode in that the `join` does not seem to actually work, rather `dumbCount(rnorm(5001))` returns `2501` fairly consistently.

Comment: Typo in `accum_nonna`? Both args `RVector` no?   I'd try to not use `NumericVector::is_na` religiously avoid everything having to do with R.

Comment: yes, sorry, they are both `RVector<double>`.

Comment: Otherwise looks reasonable.  Make it simpler -- maybe just count numbers above some threshold etc pp and compare diligently to the code in the Rcpp Gallery and RcppParallel vignette.   If all else fails post on rcpp-devel where JJ and Kevin might be more likely to chip in.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I think your comment nailed it. When removing the call to `NumericVector::is_na`, the code then works as planned. _sigh_

Comment: how it relates to tbb??

Comment: @Anton [RcppParallel](http://rcppcore.github.io/RcppParallel/#overview) ships with TBB as a backend.

Comment: I now realize that the code does _not_ work as planned when removing the `is_na` call, rather it _seems_ to work if you call it a few times. If you call it within a `replicate`, it gives bogus answers.

Comment: I can't provide a concrete answer for why this is happening, but I suspect it has something to do with your `accum_nonna` function and the fact that it is operating on iterators. Approaching this with a functor / `std::accumulate` combination instead [seems to work](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/ebeb020c54a1b25121e2), at least for your MWE.

Comment: @nrussell thanks for trying anyway. I think I will have to take a pass on `RcppParallel` until I understand why my version doesn't work but `std::accumulate` does.